# Google map v3 - attaching a url to a iframe

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to attach a URL to a iframe, When a event-listener is clicked not to sure if this is the right method.

```
var locations = [
     ['Station 1', -32.77255333509087, 151.64851427078247, 1, www.url.com],
     ['Station 2', -32.75009, 151.73467000000405, 2, www.url.com],
     ['Station 3', -32.79854, 151.64355, 3, www.url.com],

];


var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

marker = new google.maps.Marker({ 
     position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2], url: place[4]),
     map: map, icon: icon_station, animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE

});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
     return function() {
         $("#station_frame").attr("src", "URL Goes here?");
     }
})(marker, i));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `"URL goes here?"` by:

```
locations[i][4]
```

...and it should work.

Note:
This part of your code is wrong and forces a syntax-error:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2], url: place[4])
```

it has to be:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2])
```